# PyCharm unresolved reference of custom pip module

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I'm wondering about the following small issue I'm having. I'm working on a Python project, where we have installed the code as pip package with setup tools as follows:

`pip install -e ".[dev]"`

The code works, the package shows up in the virtual environment (conda), but whenever code from the package is imported, PyCharm seems to be unhappy and shows a "unresolved reference" error, underlining the import in red.

I know one can mark a folder as "Sources Root" in PyCharm but on the one hand this shouldn't be necessary in the first place, since the package is installed already and shows up using `conda list` (or `pip list` for co-workers that don't use conda) and on the other hand, the project consists of multiple such packages.

Again, project configuration is all set in PyCharm with the virtual environment and running the code from PyCharm works as intendet, I'm just wondering about the IDE showing an error where there isn't one.

Here is the project settings screen:

[image]

As shown, the packages `vision-pipeline` and `vision-debug` show up.
The one thing I need to point out is, that the imports are done with `_` instead of `-`, so

`from vision_pipeline.my_awesome_python_file import MyAwesomeClass`

for example. Naming of the folders containing the code is done in the same way.

Comment: if you open settings > project interpreter ... you see it in the list of packages? your sure its pointing to the right interpreter/virtualenv? for the whole project and not just that run config? ... if you run pip freeze in the console(using the venv that pycharm activates when you open terminal) do you see the package in the list?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes. Give me a minute, I will add a screenshot of the project settings to the question to show this.

Comment: sorry my coach is turning into a pumpkin (its past my sleep time so im gonna go do that instead :P )

Comment: Yes, I saw this question when you posted it but I'm not a regular anaconda user so I don't know how to solve this kind of problem when things don't work.